# Get selected value from select in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How can I get the client selected in the select to check if its "irpf" field is null?

I have tried to do the check for each iteration of the loop but the input fields are repeating

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('viewNuevaFacturaNegociador') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tipo_cliente">Nombre del cliente</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="id_cliente" required>
                            @foreach($users_client as $client)
                            <option value="{{ Crypt::encrypt($client->id) }}" >{{ $client->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    @if($client->irpf != null)
                    <label for="tipo_cliente">IRPF</label>
                    <input type="text" value="{{$client->irpf}}" class="form-control" disabled/>
                    @else
                    <label for="tipo_cliente">IRPF</label>
                    <input type="text" name="irpf" value="{{ old('irpf') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el porcentaje de IRPF (sin el %)" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]+" required/>
                    @endif



                    <div class="text-right">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_client" value="">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Create invoice</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: could you share your controller function

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put it in a `foreach()`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('viewNuevaFacturaNegociador') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipo_cliente">Nombre del cliente</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="id_cliente" required>
        @foreach($users_client as $client)
            <option value="{{ Crypt::encrypt($client->id) }}" >{{ $client->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    @foreach($users_client as $client)
        @if(!is_null($client->irpf))
            <label for="tipo_cliente-{{$loop->iteration}}">IRPF</label>
            <input id="tipo_cliente-{{$loop->iteration}}" type="text" value="{{$client->irpf}}" class="form-control" disabled/>
        @else
            <label for="tipo_cliente-{{$loop->iteration}}">IRPF</label>
            <input id="tipo_cliente-{{$loop->iteration}}" type="text" name="irpf" value="{{ old('irpf') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el porcentaje de IRPF (sin el %)" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]+" required/>
        @endif
    @endforeach

        <div class="text-right">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_client" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Create invoice</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**Notice:** as you're doing it in a loop, you need to care about uniqueness of `id`. I've handled it using addition of `$loop->iteration` to the end of input ids.

Comment: But this is not a solution as a text box will appear every time a user has that non-null field. What I want to do is, when choosing a user from the list, the input with its value appears, or it appears empty. But always checking with the chosen user.

Comment: If you want something dynamic on your page, you should use javascript or its variations to achieve that.